# Is creating the following for loop bad for Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have an update Method, that updates the level in the game every ms. Inside this method, i have several for loops that look like this:

```
for (int i = 0: i < 10; ++i){

}
```

When i say:

```
int i = 0
```

Does that create a lot of garbage? And would there be an alternative?

Thank you

Comment: Can you detail your question? It's hard to identify what's the actual problem

Comment: (The interesting question, should there be one, depends on what *else* happens each loop..)

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is the `inverted for loop`: **for (int i = initializer; i >= 0; i--) { ... }**, which is said to be the fastest for loop variant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `int i = 0` it creates no garbage.

The variable `i` has type `int` which is a primitive type, not an object (or reference) type.  The state of `i` is held entirely within the stack frame of the enclosing method; i.e. not on the heap.

> Does that create a lot of garbage?

No.

> And would there be an alternative?

No alternative is necessary ...